# startActivity runs for the first element in the listview but thats it

Tags: android

```
 feed
            .setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                        int position, long id) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"position is   "+ position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DetailActivity.class);
                    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

                    Log.d("listview", "variables:  "+ ((Location2) places.get(position)).getName()+" ");
                    Log.d("listview", "variables:  "+ ((Location2) places.get(position)).getImage()+" ");
                    Log.d("listview", "variables:  "+ ((Location2) places.get(position)).getDiscription()+" ");
                    i.putExtra("name", ((Location2) places.get(position)).getName());
                    i.putExtra("pic", ((Location2) places.get(position)).getImage());
                    i.putExtra("disc", ((Location2) places.get(position)).getDiscription());

                    getApplicationContext().startActivity(i);
                }
            });
```

All the data is there and is printed out in the log however the new activity only starts when it is position 0

Comment: Logcat variables happens? Anyway avoid  getApplicationContext! Use TopClass.this.startActivity

Comment: Yeah all the LogCat variables happen

Comment: Did you tried to change the startActivity call as i said?

Comment: yeah no luck with that either

Comment: @WillJamieson Did you get any sucess with my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Not quite clear about your problem. If you only show the toast message on position 0, it seems that the `onItemClick` method was only called when you clicked position 0.

Perhaps, as Marco's suggested, you can try this:

```
feed
            .setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                        int position, long id) {
                    Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "position is   " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent i = new Intent(view.getContext(), DetailActivity.class);
                    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

                    Log.d("listview", "variables:  " + ((Location2) places.get(position)).getName() + " ");
                    Log.d("listview", "variables:  " + ((Location2) places.get(position)).getImage() + " ");
                    Log.d("listview", "variables:  " + ((Location2) places.get(position)).getDiscription() + " ");
                    i.putExtra("name", ((Location2) places.get(position)).getName());
                    i.putExtra("pic", ((Location2) places.get(position)).getImage());
                    i.putExtra("disc", ((Location2) places.get(position)).getDiscription());

                    view.getContext().startActivity(i);
                }
            });
```